# Message Interruption with Vector CANoe

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I'm trying to cause messages with a certain ID (say 0x009) to lose arbitration by sending a message with a lower ID (say 0x008). The problem in my simulation setup is that I couldn't detect and then interrupt the 0x009 messages quickly enough to interrupt them. I detect them when they have already reached their destinations.

How can I detect a message's ID and then interrupt the message to win arbitration before the full transmission of that message is complete?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share the following answer from Vector's support:

"Only our CANstress tool can do this. You cannot do this with CANoe."

I'm going to try Vehicle Spy now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess u can use the IG ( Interactive Generator) node to send the message with lower ID (0x008) with a higher rate (i.e., let's say 1ms) and let the message with higher ID (0x009) to be sent by its usual rate. 
Using the Grpahical window, u will notice the delay of the messagte

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.